# Xamarin.Auth2 using google authentication error redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Hey everyone Good Day I have weird problem using Xamarin.OAuth2 for google authentication. The Login can authenticate but it seems Xamarin.Auth receive an Invalid Response from google. When I test using this URL in Google Chrome https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth… it works the page redirect to mysite URL, but using the app I receive this error redirect_uri_mismatch.

[image]

for the redirect URL i used live website.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure that the redirect URI that you are supplying to the Xamarin Auth initialization matches the one that you added into the Google Developer Console under **Authorized redirect URIs**?

For example, `https://mysite.domain.net/` below should be the same redirect URI that is listed in the **Authorized redirect URIs** field on the Google Developer Console site:

```
Xamarin.Auth.OAuth2Authenticator auth = new Xamarin.Auth.OAuth2Authenticator(
    "560741372047-t00000000000v4vf0nvp0o7aqbu94.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "sHqEPlKg0000000000iP1x",
    "openid email",
    new System.Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
    new System.Uri("https://mysite.domain.net/"),
    new System.Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"));
```

Comment: Yap it is you wont get the authentication screen if it doesnt match.

Comment: The login is success, redirect you to confirmation DENY or ALLOW when i click ALLOW the DisplayAlert pop up with that error.

Answer (score 0):

use the redirect url this way

```
public const string RedirectUrl = "com.woodenmoose.xamarin.googleauth:/oauth2redirect";
```

and

```
[Activity(Label = "GoogleAuthInterceptor")]
[
    IntentFilter
    (
        actions: new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
        {
                Intent.CategoryDefault,
                Intent.CategoryBrowsable
        },
        DataSchemes = new[]
        {
            // First part of the redirect url (Package name)
            "com.woodenmoose.xamarin.googleauth"
        },
        DataPaths = new[]
        {
            // Second part of the redirect url (Path)
            "/oauth2redirect"
        }
    )
]
```

If you're getting confused, you can refer [this project](https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/). It worked for me when I was facing the same issue.

Comment: actually I already solve the entire headache, simply by not doing a project using xamarin I am now using Android Java. So thank you.

Comment: No problem @Jake Talledo